# error in syntax with php code

Tags: php, html

I am trying to encode only synopsis from following code

```
<?php
<li><a href="?page=<?php echo base64_encode("("synopsis")&lang=hn");?>" <?php if($page == 'synopsis'){?>class="active"<?}?>>Dec</a></li>
?>
```

but when I try to encode it shows error like

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www/html/header.php on line 33

Please, help me with this syntax error. I am not able to solve it

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Leave the surrounding `<?php .. ?>` off when you use the file as a template.

You have to escape " when it is inside double quotes:

```
"(\"synopsis\")&lang=hn"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, But after escaping it does not able solve the problem, not it shows:                                                Warning: include(/var/www/html/("synopsis")&lang=en.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 23 Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/("synopsis")&lang=en.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/index.php on line 23

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this

```
<li><a href="?page=<?php echo base64_encode("(\"synopsis\")&lang=hn");?>" 
<?php if($page == 'synopsis'){?>class="active"<?}?>>Dec</a></li>
```

Comment: @ Yogesh Suther 
 
Thanks for your help, But after escaping it does not able solve the problem, not it shows: Warning: include(/var/www/html/("synopsis")&lang=en.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 23 Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/("synopsis")&lang=en.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/index.php on line 23

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes

```
<li><a href="?page=<?php echo base64_encode("('synopsis')&lang=hn");?>" <?php if($page == 'synopsis'){?>class="active"<?}?>>Dec</a></li>
```

Comment: error..use '\' before double quotes..

Comment: @MAK Thanks for your help but after using single quotes it gives error like this:                   Warning: include(/var/www/html/('synopsis')&lang=hn.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 23 Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/('synopsis')&lang=hn.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/index.php on line 23